# Keras and Tensorflow with identical weights but different test accuracy

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have trained a Tensorflow model and then built its equivalent Keras model and loaded the learned weights into it.
However, I get a different test accuracy in Keras (e.g. 98.5% in Tensorflow compared to 98%).
I have defined the accuracy in tensorflow this way:

```
accuracy = tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.argmax(input_labels, 1), tf.argmax(output, 1)), tf.float32)
```

In Keras I have used its standard metric:

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

`accuracy = model.evaluate(x=test_images, y=test_labels, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)`

I am confused where this discrepancy comes from.

**EDIT:**
Since I was not convinced with the answer, I spent a couple of days more on the code until I discovered a bug that caused this discrepancy, and after fixing it, both frameworks now produce identical results with the same weights as expected. 
I am writing this Edit to prevent any confusion for other readers, as Stackoverflow does not allow me to delete the question.

Comment: What you can/should do if you aren't satisfied with the current answer is to **post an answer of your own**. This would be better than editing the answer into the question. Do make sure, though, that your answer explains *how* you fixed the bug/discrepancy. (It's always OK to answer your own question---in fact, it's encouraged!)

Answer (score 4):

One possible reason: a dropout layer in your model.

According to [the source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L1861), the internal random logic is implemented by [tf.random_uniform](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/random_uniform), which will randomly generate a new value on each call to `sess.run()`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, there is a dropout layer. But I thought all the dropout layers become deterministic at the test phase and all the nodes are switched on, so there should not be any randomness due to that. Is that wrong?

Comment: I removed the dropout layer and still get different accuracies in keras and tensorflow. However, now the accuracy of Keras is much lower (e.g. 70% in keras compared to 90% in tensorflow). Still don't know what causes this.

Comment: I just updated my answer for your first comment, for the second one, it looks strange, maybe you can post more information about your model.  @Monaj

Comment: Thanks for your response, but please correct me if I am wrong. I still reckon `tf.tandom_uniform` comes into play at the Training phase. Once Training is done, every thing becomes deterministic and at the Test time, all neurons are on and take effect via the already learned weights.

Comment: @Monaj No, tf will randomly generate this value for both training and testing phrase, because it's not a variable to be trained in the dropout layer.

Comment: I see, so with no dropout layer, they should produce same result. I guess I should look into the code in more detail to see what has gone wrong.